# how to detect connection failed in node js?

Tags: node.js

I use `net.connect` to make socket connection, I wonder how to detect it when a connection has failed?

It seems this doesn't work

```
 //this will return a net.Socket and automatically connect
 var client = net.connect({port:22000, host:'10.123.9.163'});

 //doesn't trigger a error event even if connection fails
 client.on('error', (err)=>{console.log('something wrong')});

 //now an error event is emitted reasonably
 client.write('hello');
```

when I run this piece of code, the connection should fail, and it indeed fails because when I write some data, an error occurs. But, I can not detect the connection failure. How can I do that?

=====Ready to close======

God damn it, I think I have just make a mistake. In fact the connection succeeded but due to some security strategy the server close the connection, I find out by doing a telnet. After trying other port which should definitely fail, the error event is emitted, everything go normal as expected. So, I am gonna close this question in case of misleading other people, and also thank you guys for helping me :)

Comment: Could you try with `close` and `timeout` events?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most portable way is to simply implement a 'ping-pong' check where both sides send some kind of 'ping' request every so often. If `n` outstanding ping requests go unanswered after some period of time, then consider the connection dead. This kind of algorithm is basically what OpenSSH uses for example (although it's not enabled by default).